# Bxslider infiniteLoop is not working

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I need in my slider to show the first image and continue loop after the last image.I use bx slider code like this

here is my code

```
<ul id="slide_slide">
<li>
<img src="img/1.jpg" alt="img06"/><li>
<li>
<img src="img/2.jpg" alt="img06"/><li>
<li>
<img src="img/3.jpg" alt="img06"/><li>
<li>
<img src="img/4.jpg" alt="img06"/><li>
</ul>
```

and the script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#slide_slide').bxSlider({
   auto: true,
   infiniteLoop:true,
   pager:false,
   moveSlides:1,
   nextText:'',
   prevText:''
});  

});
 </script>
```

but when showing the slider the after the last image noting will show the loop is not working. What should be changed to enable loop view?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#slide_slide').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    slideWidth: 300,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 1,
    slideMargin: 10
});
```

This is working fine for me.